# Why do Sitecore virtual users not change Sitecore.Context.User?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Why AuthenticationManager.Login doesn't change Sitecore.Context.User it is always Anonymous ?

```
   string userName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", "extranet", "Login");     
            Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User virtualUser =  SC.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(userName, isAuthenticated);

 Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(virtualUser.Name);
```

or is this the right behavior ?
How does Sitecore process access to pages in this case ?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to use Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.GetActiveUser() to retrieve the logged in user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AuthenticationManager.Login()` should change the context user.

Are you sure the user is logged in?

You can check the result value of the `AuthenticationManager.Login()`. It returns  true if the user is logged in, otherwise you still see the Anonymous user.

Here a sample code of how to create a virtual user, assign a Role to it and log in:

```
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user = Sitecore.Security.Authentication
.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(@"domain\user",true);

if(user!=null)
{
  string domainRole = @"domain\role";

  if(Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.Exists(domainRole))
  {
    user.Roles.Add(Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.FromName(domainRole));
  }

  Sitecore.Security.UserProfile profile = user.Profile;
  profile.FullName = "full name";
  profile.Save();
  Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(user.Name);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but Login(user.Name) dosn't work it is working in case it send full Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User object.

Comment: There is indeed an overlaod method Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(User) that takes a Sitecore.Security.Accuonts.User object as parameter.

Comment: Modified the answer to use `RuntimeSettings`